# How to render arbitrary post without displaying it

Tags: posts

I need to emulate rendering of a post and repeat this action with a list of posts, because during rendering I have a `do_action('get_my_info', $key, $value)`, which helps to collect a special piece of data.

So, in the admin panel, I want to click a button and then the Wordpress starts processing posts as usual one by one and do actions assigned to the `get_my_info` hook. As a result, I get the data collected from every processed post, which I will manage in the code later. By the 'Rendering' I mean complete processing of all shortcodes, hooks, etc., which corresponds to preparing the final HTML.

As I know, Wordpress pushes a generated page to the user at the end of the PHP script. And I need to come to 'the end' a number of times and start over again within the common script.

In a formal language

`1. WP script starts 
...
2. I initiate data collection
<loop begins>
2.1. WP starts processing 1st post
2.2. WP process shorcodes and other plugins
2.3. WP do_action('get_my_info');
2.4. WP provide final HTML without showing it
<loop ends>
3. I process collected data
4. WP begins the usual rendering and shows me the page`

I have started from `admin_init` hook, where I initialized my object that will collect needed information. The last hook that produces the result of gathering and analyzing information is the `shutdown`.

So, in the basic flow, between these hooks WP renders a response. It doesn't produce an HTML page for a visitor, but I need to make Wordpress to go through all hooks for the client side, like it is rendering basic posts, do all 'stuff' that is responsible for that action between `wp` hook and `shutdown`. Between these hooks I am hooking others (no matter what the logic does). And I need to repeat this flow again and again.

Comment: Could you not skip the rendering of the posts part and just do the special action? What exactly is that action btw? Is it a piece of javascript? A PHP shortcode? What kind of file handling is being done? The question cannot be answered with just the information you've provided, more is needed, please edit your question to be clearer

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, please, look on the updated content.

Comment: How is your `do_action` call being triggered? is it inside a shortcode? It looks like you're trying to show a censored version of your problem to hide what you're trying to do, but it's making your question impossible to answer or even understand the mechanics. What does your shortcode actually do? And where does it get its information ( the key/value pairs )

Comment: No, it isn't a censored version. do_action() is triggered when a filter applies. It is not inside a shortcode. I meant that I need that every shortcode was rendered.

Comment: BTW, don't bear in mind my 'action'. Let think about the task alike getting all final HTMLs of pages in one request.

Comment: I ask about your action because it would provide direly needed context. If I wanted to replicate a simplified version of what you have right now I could not, and I don't understand the mechanics of what you're doing because you're censoring the context around it. Since you mention you use filters, which filters do you use? Does this processing happen on the loop? During `setup_postdata`? Note that WP doesn't push the page all in one go, it outputs as it's output, it doesn't collect it all up and send it out at once. By the time shortcodes get rendered the title and the headers are already sent

Comment: I don't understand why you don't understand, really. There is just needed to render a couple of posts into HTML and that's it. Imagine that you open several pages in your browser and WP rendering several time pages and push it to you. But in my case, I won't that WP pushes you a page any time it renders that. I just want the WP runs rendering with all hooked functions several times till the `shutdown` hook appears.

Comment: The problem is that the concept of 'render a few posts' is foreign and not how WordPress works. Since there are no examples and no clear ways to reproduce the mechanism you ask about, it's unclear and ambiguous. If you could provide a primitive example of what you're doing it would make the entire process significantly easier to understand. Right now it's not clear what kind of processing you're talking about, or what the desired end result is. Just that if you displayed a post template "stuff" happens

Comment: The only concrete thing we have is that at some point a `get_my_info` hook is called, but we don't know what calls it, how it's called, what gets passed to it, or what it does, nor do we know how the data is collected and which actions and filters are used, the nature of the data, or what shortcodes are present. There is a huge amount of ambiguity that you're unaware of. E.g. are you pulling data from the shortcodes and compiling it into a report? Or are you analysing the final text passed to `the_content`? Or is it statistics on which shortcodes are used?

Comment: Or are there other functions called in the templates used that impact the result? Please provide a solid hard example of what you're currently doing, describing it is not working. Again WP doesn't "render" a post then push it to you, it happens in realtime incrementally in the template, not as a pre-fabricated result of a singular process, what you describe is not how it works, and since your entire explanation rests on that premise, it's very difficult to understand

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you very much for your attitude! I'll try to give more concrete example.

Comment: BTW, I've already found the solution, which is not native to WP. I am using TWIG template engine. And, in this case, I am able to run and render whatever I need multiple times through the whole posts and then to continue with a basic response to the user.